# A thin rod is given a charge $Q$ distributed evenly along its length $L$. Find the electric potential along the axis of the rod as a function of $x$..

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

A thin rod is given a charge $Q$ distributed evenly along its length $L$. Find the electric potential along the axis of the rod as a function of $x$, the distance from one end of the rod.

Notice how it says *from one end*. This is the part that is confusing me.

The answer:
$$V=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon _o L}\ln \left(\frac{x+L}{x}\right)$$

What I have tried:

$$V(x)=k\int \frac{dq}{x}$$
$dq=\lambda dx$

substitute for $dq$

$$V(x)=k\int \frac{\lambda dx}{x}$$

take the lambda out

$$V(x)=k\lambda \int \frac{dx}{x}$$

But this is kind of a nonsense answer. I believe the problem is asking for the electric potential *including* the rod but I am not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: sketch]
I assume this is the setup. The point at which you want to find the potential is a distance $x$ away from one end of the rod, which is of length $L$. Now, we want to sum over contributions from all the bits of the rod, and we need a variable to keep track of where on the rod we are while we're doing this - I will call this $x'$. Now, we get
$$V(x)=\int \frac{k\,dq}{r}=k\int_{x}^{x+L}\frac{\lambda\,dx'}{x'}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 L}\ln\left(\frac{x+L}{x}\right)$$
which is what you need.